# iPhone - How to determine the deployment target iOS version of an existing project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, backwards-compatibility

I have an existing huge iOS project, set for iOS 5.0 target by default. But I'm pretty sure that it is also 4.?.? compliant.

How may I know the minimum iOS version my app can be targeted to, without having to compare the whole code word by word with the iOS documentation to know for each method/constant/... the iOS version it was introduced, and at the end, know what minimum iOS version I can target ? That would take weeks !

(XCode does not help... Setting the iOS target to something lower that iOS 5 never raises any warning nor error when compiling, so I don't know for example, which methods are only available for iOS 4.2 when setting target version to iOS 4.1...)

Comment: can not understand what do you want?

Comment: i think you should set it to 3.2 that is enough for all the devices and no warning should be appear, isn' it?

Comment: @HardikShah:this is not because I set the min target version to 3.2 that my code is 3.2 compliant.

Comment: Oliver, see my answer below. Unless you have a device running 3.2 to test on, the earliest OS you should target is 4.3, which is the earlier that the simulator allow you to test.

Answer (score 2):

If you've used any iOS 5 APIs then the app will crash when that code tries to execute on iOS 4.x unless you put in some code to check that the methods are available before calling them (look up "respondsToSelector:" in the documentation).

Set your deployment target to iOS 4.3. In the simulator, in the top-left drop down it should offer you a choice of iOS 5 or 4.3 simulators. Select 4.3, then test your app thoroughly, if it crashes you can check the console log to find the offending API call and then work out what to do about it.

If you can't see 4.3 in the build dropdown then you must have still got 5.0 as your deployment target.

I suggest not setting the deployment target any earlier than 4.3 unless you have a test device running an earlier OS that you can use.

So the answer to your question is, the deployment target should be the earliest version of iOS that you are able to test the app on (either with the simulator or an actual device), unless you rely on APIs in later OS versions and can't work around them.

Comment: Nice idea, but how do you do make the app run if it has features that need a device to run on, such as a camera, a gyro, an accelerometer, a gps, ... ? The app has all of that.

Comment: @Oliver that is a different question as they depend on hardware, not the iOS version. There are ways of checking for all those things you mentioned. You may wish to check for them on app start up.

Comment: @Oliver, you can either check the docs for the camera, accelerometer, etc. APIs and make sure you're not using any iOS5 features, or you can get a second phone for testing and install an earlier iOS version on it. The latter option is what the pros do (I have a suite of five iPhones, iPods Touches and iPads on various OSes) but it is an expensive option if you're just starting out as a developer.

Comment: You can buy a refurbished iPod Touch 4th gen from the Apple refurbished store on apple.com relatively cheaply. That will probably come with iOS 4 out of the box, or you can downgrade it if not. It will let you test camera, accelerometer and although it doesn't have GPS, the location APIs will still work the same way (they use Skyhook instead of GPS on a touch).

Answer (score 0):

In the build setting of your target , you can search for the deployment target. That will give you the information about the minimum version of iOS for which this app was developed.

Comment: No, that just tell the min version the app is supposed to work on, even if it's not true.